# Getting two unique values from two Java Collection objects

Tags: java, collections, unique

I would like to get unique values from two Collection objects. How would I do that? 
Example: Let us take two `ArrayLists`:

```
List bag1 = new ArrayList(); 
List bag2 = new ArrayList();

bag1.add("1");
bag1.add("2");
bag1.add("3");
bag1.add("7");
bag1.add("8");
bag1.add("9");

bag2.add("4");
bag2.add("5");
bag2.add("6");
bag2.add("7");
bag2.add("8");
bag2.add("9");
```

I need to get a result like --> 1,2,3 from `bag1` and 4,5,6 from `bag2`

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Use org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.disjunction(Collection a, Collection b);
2. Bag isn't the best variable name for a list. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Sets instead. The Java Collection has a few classes which deal with this. The idea is you could just the the set difference between the two collections, and you'll get your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. However one interviewer asked me how to get it done if you use ArrayList Object. Appreciate your time to look into this question.

Comment: If its an interviewer, shouldn't you do your due diligence instead of asking for the answer outright?

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'set' to store your data. That way your collection will have unique elements as and when you add elements to the set.

See the javadoc over here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried...

```
bag1.removeAll(bag2);
```

If you want to keep bag1 and bag2 intact you can use a Set variable and pass all values of `bag1` into the `Set` and then check for `contains()` like

```
    Set set = new HashSet();
    set.addAll(bag2);
    for(Object o: bag1){
        if(!set.contains(o)){
            // Do whatever you want with bag1 elements
        }
    }
    set.clear();

    set.addAll(bag1);
    for(Object o: bag2){
        if(!set.contains(o)){
            // Do whatever you want with bag2 elements
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `removeAll` method define in the [Set interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Set.html#re).

```
Set intersect = new TreeSet(bag1);  
intersect.removeAll(bag2);  
List unique1 = Arrays.asList(intersect);  

intersect = new TreeSet(bag2);  
intersect.removeAll(bag1);  
List unique2 = Arrays.asList(intersect);
```